# FireBase RecyclerView FavoriteList

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase In my application and in my database i have favorite List for eachUser, but i have a problem when i click on the icon Add favorite in the recycler View it checked twice like the figure bellow ( i have 2 separated icon, icon for add to favorite icon to delete) 
[image]

This is the following Source Code ( this code on the bindView Holder)

```
 holder.mFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();

            user.put("nomPoste", filActualiteData.getNomPoste());
            user.put("nomEntreprise", filActualiteData.getNomEntreprise());
            user.put("date", filActualiteData.getDate());
            user.put("ville", filActualiteData.getVille());
            user.put("id", filActualiteData.getId());
            saveUserFavorite(user);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            holder.mFavC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });


    FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference favoriteRef = rootRef.collection("usersFavorite").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("Favorite");
    favoriteRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for ( final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    favID = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("IDDoc", document.getString("id"));
                    Log.d("FilActualitéID", filActualiteData.getId());
                    if (filActualiteData.getId().trim().equals(document.getString("id")))
                    {
// -- >problem here 
                        favID.put("Docid",document.getId());
                        favID.put("idValue",document.getString("id"));
                        Log.d("MapSize",String.valueOf(favID.size()));
                        final String docid= document.getId();
                        holder.mFavC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.mFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    holder.mFavC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("usersFavorite").document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).collection("Favorite").document(docid).delete();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            holder.mFavC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.mFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Even if im scrooling FavIcon is duplicated all recycler

Comment: I need to save recyclerView State inside fragment because when i scrool favorite iCon is replicate, also i need to handle on Click Favorite Item ( because it checked twice ) any solution pleasa?

Comment: if you have additional information, you can add that to your question by clicking the edit link under it. That way you can leave comments for folks that have questions.

Comment: Any answer please?